# padding based on label not input box css

Tags: html, css

I currently have a form that is setup much like the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8bbaF/2/

I am trying to get each input box to have a set amount of whitespace between them. Currently the formatting is based on the length of each label. I would like the formatting to be independent of label length. The labels are currently on top of the input box and they must stay there. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="inputForm">
<form id="newInput">

    <div class="inputFields">
        <label for="lists">Lists<input name="lists"/></label>
        <label for="new1">New Field 1<input name="new1"/></label>

    </div>
    <div class="inputFields">
        <label for="lists">Listswqwerqwer<input name="lists"/></label>
        <label for="new1">New Field 1<input name="new1"/></label>

    </div>

</form>
```

CSS:

```
.inputForm label{
    display:inline-block;
}
div.inputFields{
    display:inline-block;
}
.inputFields input{
    padding-right:3%;
}
```

Comment: Hi Chris: if I understand you right, you want two fields per line, with the label left justified on top of each input field, and you want the input fields lined up like on a grid.

Comment: Don't user percentages for padding. Used a fixed value, in pixels.

Comment: Marc that is correct, Diodeus can you explain the benefits of using pixels over percentages? I recently read on SO that percentages are better than pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give each of the `inputFields` containers a set margin and adjust your CSS slightly:

**CSS**

```
.inputFields {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.inputFields label,
.inputFields input {
    display: block;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4svcA/2/)**

Comment: Both answers work and adequately address my problem, I gave the answer to the new guy since he has no reputation yet...

Comment: Changed my mind, the first answer I accepted messed up some other aspects of the formatting. I plugged this in and it worked perfectly.
Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Chris.Stover I was totally on-board with the concept of helping out new users that have good suggestions, but I'm glad this was helpful as well. I tend to personally separate out the `label` and `input` elements like Christoffer Hald suggested. It tends to give you a bit more control over exactly how to style them, especially if you are doing validation.

Answer (score 2):

Don't place the input fields within the labels. Its causing lots of problems. Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/8bbaF/6/

```
<div class="inputForm">
<form id="newInput">

    <div class="inputFields">
        <label for="lists">Lists</label><input name="lists"/>
        <label for="new1">New Field 1</label><input name="new1"/>

    </div>
    <div class="inputFields">
        <label for="lists">Lists</label><input name="lists"/>
        <label for="new1">New Field 1</label><input name="new1"/>

    </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
<div class="inputForm">
    <form id="newInput">
        <div class="inputFields">
            <label for="lists">Lists</label>
            <input name="lists" />
        </div>
        <div class="inputFields">
            <label for="new1">New Field 1</label>
            <input name="new1" />
        </div>
        <div class="inputFields">
            <label for="lists">Listswqwerqwer</label>
            <input name="lists" />
        </div>
        <div class="inputFields">
            <label for="new1">New Field 1</label>
            <input name="new1" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

With the CSS

```
div.inputFields {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 40%;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

.inputForm label {
    display: block;
}
.inputFields input {
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
}
```

And the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/pg8Kh/

I see others got here first with essentially the same idea.  There is some variation depending on how you want to place the fields on your layout grid.

However, the key is keeping the `<label>` as a separate element.

Comment: I like this solution as well but I would have to go back through the forms and insert a new div at every input. Since some forms have over 40 different inputs this would create a major headache.

Comment: Nesting a control element such as `input` inside of the `label` associated with it is technically [valid HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/label). It is mainly a structural decision.

Comment: @Ruben Infante - thank you for your comment, I read your reference and updated my post accordingly.  Good to review the basics!